# Securing Spring web app by checking client's IP v4 address

Tags: security, spring, authentication, ipv6, ipv4

In a Spring 3 based web app I am using a custom implementation of AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider to not only to check the username/password pair but also the IP address of the client. However, when I call within `retrieveUser()`:

```
@Override
protected UserDetails retrieveUser(String username, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    ...
    String ipAddr = ((WebAuthenticationDetails)authentication.getDetails()).getRemoteAddress();
    ...
    User user = ...
    return user;
}
```

it returns `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0`. That will be the IP v6 address for localhost. How can I check now against a white list of IP v4 addresses if that method returns me a IP v6 address? Can I provide compatibility with IP v4 and v6 for the whitelist? Thank you for your insights!

Comment: Do you use any Proxy (Apache HTTP Server for example)?

Comment: I am developing on a local Apache Tomcat 7 server. Is that the reason? If yes, can I tell Tomcat to give me IP v4 addresses instead? PS: Wow, you're fast.

Comment: I asked, because you need to configure some extra stuff if you use a proxy. - But if you do not use one, then the problem is an other one.

Comment: @Ralph: Thank you for your idea. But the proxy does not seem to be the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is your local Tomcat, then try to invoke it not by `http://localhost:8080/...`, try to invoke it by `http://127.0.0.1:8080/..`

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but still relevant.  Adding the following parameter to your startup script/run configuration will provide you with ipV4 addresses and not ipV6.

-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true